# Haag's theorem inequivalence equivalent to orthogonality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory

In ["Who proved Haag's theorem?"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5165E63EC67B289A447C13DD1A35F1A2?doi=10.1.1.615.2449&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Tracy Lupher writes:

> In modern operator theory it is a well known mathematical fact that
>   two irreducible representations are unitarily inequivalent if and
>   only if they are orthogonal.

I would like to find a proof in the case of finite groups. Can we use Schur's lemma to show that orthogonality is equivalent to inequivalence?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: From a both logical and mathematical point of view, how can representations be orthogonal? The term "orthogonal" applies to vectors, once a sesqui-/bilinear form is defined on a vector space, while a representation is typically understood as a mapping (function, operator) from an algebraic object to the algebra of (linear) operators on some (topological) vector space.

Comment: The author is talking about subrepresentatiions on orthogononal subspaces

Comment: of a Hilbert space.